# REST API method path naming in Micro Service

Tags: rest, uri, microservices

There is a service which will provide registration functionality for a service to clients. One of the methods will provide a list of all applications submitted by a user. From the below options what **should** be OR is the **better** uri/path for such a method based on REST and Microservices principles.

1. /users/{id}/enrollments
2. /users/{id}/enrollments/list
3. /api/enrollments/submitter-id/{id}
4. /enrollments/{id}/list

Answer (score 0):

To answer this question maybe a bit more information is needed, eg a very high level overview of the architecture which would tell what are the resources that you have identified for your system.
Now a basic understanding behind url formation is forming it around a resource https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource-oriented_architecture.

Eg : Say your are building restfull apis where user is trying to enroll for a Course. Here resources can be like course, topic, lesson etc.
Now to get list of topics provided, a url can look like

```
GET /topics -> gets all the topics.
GET /topics/{id} -> gets specific topic.
POST /topics -> creates new topic.
PUT /topic/{id} -> updates a particular topic.
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: Thanks. Building on your eg. say a person has enrolled for multiple courses. Now what would be appropriate url for it?

Comment: Well I would say considering that a "Person" is a "Student" and is a resource so the url would look like :-
GET /students/{id}
and this would give the info which will contain say names and ids of courses the person/student is enrolled to.